# How To Use VBA To Share Excel File With Fellow Office User?

Tags: excel, vba, office365

How does one use vba to share an excel file with another office user? I have a template that needs to be customized slightly and shared as a separate workbook with hundreds of users (same active directory).

I have a table mapping out what files should be shared with what users as shown here:
[image]

I thought I could use a sharing method to set the permissions using [MSOPermission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msopermission). I've tried quite a few approaches which have all failed, but these were the ones I was most optimistic would work:

```
wkBk.Permission.Add "bill_User@company.com",msoPermissionEdit
wkBk.Permission.Add "SallyCEO@company.com",msoPermissionRead
wkBk.Permission.Add "billy_companyID",msoPermissionEdit
```

The specific error I receive ([shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8tgM.png)) indicates something is wrong with the `Permission Object`. I can't find much documentation on this (a common pet-peeve of mine with Microsoft).

I've seen a couple posts shown below, but none address my question.

- [Automate File sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866282/automate-file-sharing)
- [Share and unshare file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457504/vba-shared-workbook-and-unshared-workbook)
- [Permission sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550761/workbook-permissions-in-vba-macros)

I'm sure I'm in the wrong area or maybe I need to enable a library. I'm embarrassed to say that I even attempted to use the macro recorder, but no code was logged when I interacted with the sharing menu [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ7zN.png).

### Bonus Question

It's possible that VBA is not the best tool for handling my use-case situation. If there's a better automation method for my situation such as [TypeScript](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript) or [Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/), I will upvote any suggestions that include basic instructions or a reference with specific terms/procedures that I could use to hunt down an overall solution. Thanks.

*Note to Microsoft:* Executing this comparable task in [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/) is easy and [well documented](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addEditor(String)):

```
ss.addEditor("billyTheUser@gmail.com");
ss.addViewer("sallyCEO@gmail.com");
```

Comment: Greetings! Have you tried ["Use of the Permission object raises an error when the Windows Rights Management client is not installed."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Office.Permission)

Comment: Hi @Sgdva, i did see that article and tried it, but it throws an error on the line `Set irmPermission = ActiveWorkbook.Permission`. I wasn't sure if that was true VBA or VB (it says  both). That doesn't mean it's the wrong approach though...

Comment: I was unable to successfully invoke `.Permission.Add` until I set `.Permission.Enabled = True`. This assignment took a while to complete (about 5 seconds). From then on, `.Permission.Add` worked, even after closing Excel and creating a new workbook, not calling `.Permission.Enabled` ever after. It's as if Excel, Office or Windows had installed or activated some capability for subsequent usage (the WRM client mentioned by @Sgdva?).

Answer (score 1):

PowerApps was mentioned - assuming you have a standard O365 license and SharePoint Online available then it's possible to set access as needed here's an illustration from an SPO Documents library file:

[image]

Microsoft Documentation:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782

Option 4 from this article:
https://sharepointmaven.com/6-locations-can-set-security-files-sharepoint-office-365/

Comment: thank you @kshkarin. There doesn't appear to be a VBA solution, so I appreciate the tip for a workaround. Upvoted.

Comment: @PGSystemTester this video seems to be in the right direction https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ahYoy5L3ec&t=1929s, you'd need to query LDAP in VBA to get the user identities, and even then it's not a guaranteed solution since VBA (or password protected VBA) can still be circumvented.

Comment: The simple and robust solution is using SharePoint and managing permissions in the file library.

Comment: Thanks. That plain-text password isn't going to cut it. I can rip through a VBA editor protection without even minimizing Excel. I appreciate the Sharepoint approach though. I still just find it hard to believe that a task so simple cannot be automated.  Again Google Sheets has this available in the same basic procedures as opening a workbook  (I am complaining to Microsoft... not you )